# xamDataTree start edit of a node in code

Tags: wpf, infragistics

I must not be Googling this right.

In an event handler (from a context menu), I want to force an Infragistics xamDataTree into edit mode of a node. As in: right-click, context menu, select Edit, context menu closes and we're in edit mode on the node.

(I know how to do the update, the binding is correct, I have a fully-working dynamically-built context menu, all I need is the "Start Editing This Node" magic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, it is that simple:

`TreeControl.EnterEditMode(nodeToEdit);`